# Bug with updating multiple documents with $inc in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have encountered strange behavoir while testing my application.
I have a request to update multiple documents and increment one of thier fields by 1 (and also decrease other by -1, but dont think that this is the point).

```
Query = { "_id" : { "$in" : [ObjectId("4fbf8481a975b5237c56f221"),
                             ObjectId("4fbf8481a975b5237c56f222"),
                             ObjectId("4fbf8481a975b5237c56f223")] } };
Update = { "$inc" : { "PartlyCompleted" : -1, "Completed" : 1 } }
```

The first document updates OK, but two others are not affected.

What could be the reason. Please give me advise where to look.

Some aditional information. I'm using C# official driver. Here is some of the code:

```
_personsId = new BsonArray();
_personsId.AddRange(personsId.Where(x => DataService.IsIdValid(x)).
                              Select(x => new ObjectId(x)).ToArray());

var query = Query.In("_id", _personsId);
var update = Update.Combine(
                    Update.Inc("Completed", 1 ),
                    Update.Inc("PartlyCompleted", -1));

DataService.PersonSet.Collection.Update(query, update);
```

I also checked the number of documents returned by the query below, and it is 3:

```
    var count = DataService.PersonSet.Collection.Count(query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default updates affect only the first matched document.

So, in your example mongo picks one of those 3 documents and increments counters. To update multiple documents you need to set the `UpdateFlags.Multi` flag.

I am curious, do you use this flag in other updates? If yes, why the question? If no, are you sure those updates touch multiple documents at once?

Comment: Really big Tnx!
I started to suspect something when noticed boolean properties in mongo docs. but really belived that multi is turned on by default.
I runned oldertests one more time and they all failed. Dont really know who came they was passed before. Not properly builded project or i was too inattentive;
Sorry for such stupid question, and tnx again =)

Comment: No problem. Now it's a chance to improve your tests :)